# I cannot grab a value from an input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, input

I have a couple of input boxes that get dynamically created, and then filled. When I try and read these, I just get "undefined" as an answer. This pisses me off, because the same code works everywhere on other places on my web app. 
The code I use for grabbing the value looks like this:

```
$('#box1.1').val()
```

So this SHOULD return the value of element with id = "box1.1", am I right?

Firebug console:

```
>>> $('#box1.1').val()
undefined
```

And yes, I do use jQuery. Version 1.6.2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your selector is trying to get this element: `<input id="box" class="1" />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should escape the dot with two backslashes so jQuery doesn't treat `.1` as a class.

```
$('#box1\\.1').val();
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F

Answer (score 4):

It is generally best to think of the `$` function in jQuery as something which accepts a comma delineated list of CSS selectors. In CSS, the `.` means, "object with the class name of..." Therefore, jQuery is looking for something under the box1 id which has the class of 1. Basically, in this example:

```
<div id="box1"><span class="1"></span></div>
```

jQuery would return the span. In this example:

```
<div id="box1.1"><span class="not_1"></span></div>
```

jQuery necessarily returns `undefined`.

Because your ID causes conflicts in CSS, then your best bet is to simply remove the `.` from the class names themselves. Normally an `_` or a `-` would be preferable.

Comment: this is definitely the most simplistic example. the . syntax is reserved to delineate a class, but you started with a hash(#) for an ID. these are conflicting and causing your undefined return value.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a valid id (in jQuery's parlance at least): "box1.1". You cannot have a dot in the id as it'll confuse the jQuery selector engine since dot usually means a class name.

You can change the id to say: "box1_1" and try.

Here's a demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UnUYP/

Comment: As per HTML spec, yes. But not in jQuery's parlance! Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, the period has special meaning. They're used to prefix class selectors. There's no way for jQuery to know that .1 is part of the ID and not some CSS class named 1. You should instead use a character that doesn't have a special meaning, e.g. an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

No that is looking for an element with the id of "box1" with a class applied named "1"...
In a jquery selector the # refers to an id selector (css selector) and the . refers to a class name. Best practice to avoid using periods for id values